# Is it possible to run java code when activity is not launched?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on an alarm java application.
I want to run `Alarm();` function when the systems clock arrives to the `targetTime`.
But I want to do these even the application is not open.
So somehow I want to run it in androids background.

My code :

```
void AlarmCheck (DateTimeAlarm currentTime, DateTimeAlarm targetTime)
{
    if(!targetTime.alarmed && currentTime.day == targetTime &&
        currentTime.hour == targetTime.hour && currentTime.minute >= targetTime.minute)
    {
        targetTime.alarmed = true;
        Alarm();
    }
}
```

And this is the class for the `DateTimeAlarm` :

```
public class DateTimeAlarm
{
    public int day;
    public int hour;
    public int minute;
    public bool alarmed = false;

    public DateTimeAlarm(int day, int hour, int minute)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute= minute;
    }
}
```

I have no idea where to put this code PLEASE HELP ME.

I am new to java so please explain easily. thank you for any suggesions.

Comment: The short answer is you can't, while you can read about `alarmManager` to set an alarm https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager, but there is no gurantee that it would trigger on time, or would trigger at all. There is `doze mode` which would kill your app and many other things which won't let your app to trigger the alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the time when you start learning about services.
If you want long running operations in background, you must make a service to do that for you. I leave the link to the official site for you.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It has become really difficult to do background tasks in Android using Services, use a WorkManager instead: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager